# Show Image Canvas Javascript after upload files with File Reader

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, filereader

So I'm trying to display image on canvas using File Reader. But it won't work. I don't know where the problem is.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("ourCanvas"),
context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
uploadedFile = document.getElementById('uploaded-file');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initImageLoader);

function initImageLoader() {
  uploadedFile.addEventListener('change', handleManualUploadedFiles);
  function handleManualUploadedFiles(ev){
    var file = ev.target.files[0];
    handleFile(file);
  }

}


function handleFile(file) {
  var imageType = /image.*/;

  if(file.type.match(imageType)){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
      var tempImageStore = new Image();

      tempImageStore.onLoad = function(ev){
        canvas.height = ev.target.height;
        canvas.width = ev.target.width;
        context.drawImage(ev.target, 0, 0);
      }
      tempImageStore.src = event.target.result;
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

After I upload the file, image don't show on the Canvas, and does'nt show anything wrong in Console. Is there any problem with my code?

Comment: Typo: `onLoad` is not the same as `onload`, case matters in JS.

Comment: Beside, if you're not targeting utterly old browsers, you'd be better using an ImageBitmap for this task `async function handleFile(file) { const bmp = await createImageBitmap(file); canvas.width = bmp.width; canvas.height = bmp.height; context.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0); }`